# Revert changes made to working directory

Tags: git, git-branch

I have the following problem. I create 2 files unnecessary in my working directory
and I want to eliminate them
I try with git checkout , but this didn't work

```
fernando@fernando:~/GIT/octobox$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   a.txt
#   b.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
fernando@fernando:~/GIT/octobox$ git checkout .
fernando@fernando:~/GIT/octobox$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   a.txt
#   b.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git clean`, maybe like this.

```
git clean -f
```

Comment: I'M sorry for the question. The files yet aren't managed for git